# Develop Android App With Smart Bracelet

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

I am studying the possibility of developing an android app using a "fitness smart bracelet", we want to access the data from the device etc.

The problem we find is that most smart bracelet do not provide an open API or SDK for developing purposes. This is just a brief of what we found till now:

- FitBit and Jawbonew do provide a SDK but we find the devices too
  spensive, the sme happens with Microsoft device
- We found some resources for developing using the Mi Band bracelet
  but these libraries are not official and are developed for third
  party sources, despite of that we see that some people have published
  apps using these methods, is this totally legal?
- Another option could be get in touch with some bracelet manufacturer and check if they are interested in provide a device that meet our requirements and provide appropriate SDK to achieve our purposes, but does not seems n easy task, does anyone know about a company that can provide these kind of service.
- We checked out that in Alibaba there are lot of devices that say
  they have a SDK but we could not find more information about them, does anyone have any experience with these suppose SDK??
- Last question is that we found some official resources about access Bluetooth Low energy devices like this link:

  https://newcircle.com/s/post/1553/bluetooth_smart_le_android_tutorial

  Does anyone have experience about how far can we get using these
  technology with any smart bracelet, is it totally legal?

Any light is well appreciated.

Comment: I'd say that it is a waste of time trying to make your app work with most of Smart Bracelets, since, as you said - most of them don't have open SDK. Also there will be new devices with new SDK (or without it) released frequently, and you'll have to update your app to support new devices. What I can suggest is to focus on Android Wear devices, which are standardized, and have an open APi for fitnes data

Comment: Thank u Vlad Matvienko for your comment, unfortunately android wear only have watches, not fit smart bracelets IP68 that fits our requirements. By other hand we can not find a proper device with open sdk woth good price. And we have another doubt, is it legal to develop an app without a official sdk from the manufacter??

Comment: Despite the fact that you seem to have a well researched question - you seem to be asking for a tutorial or off site resource in the form of an SDK, is that correct?

Comment: it themes that you are going to do a serious ammount of work on it, so you'd better speak to a lawer about this question, but as for me, I'm 99% sure that it is legal since it is nothing except a regular bluetooth device.

Comment: Right, If we want to access the features of a Device we supose the manufacter must provide information about how to access and control the hardware and can not find such resources

Comment: Sounds like you found a new business opportunity.  Forget the app, start making open bracelets with an open API for other devs in your position.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice, which is off-topic. Legal questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/.